# Create Sublime Text build system for build and source in different directories

Tags: build, sublimetext2

I have a project for which the build and source directories are not the same. I'd like to create a [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html) that will build in the `build` directory while I am editing in the `source` directory.

Let's say I have this directory structure:

- /home/dbw/src *The source files.*
- /home/dbw/bld *The build files.*

*(shocking and unique naming system, I know - let's hold the applause until the end, shall we?)*

The build is nested many layers deep, and the directory structures are symmetric.  From a directory in the `source`, I would like Sublime to start a build in the related `build` directory.  For instance, if I am editing /home/dbw/src/foo/Makefile, I'd like make to execute in /home/dbw/bld/foo.  I've tried this:

```
{
  "cmd": ["make"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "/home/dbw/bld/${file_path/$project_path//}",
  "selector": "source.makefile",

  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Clean",
      "cmd": ["make", "clean"]
    },
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "cmd": ["make", "test"]
    }
  ]
}
```

My .sublime-project is in /home/dbw/src

I also tried using `"working_dir": "/home/dbw/bld/${file_path/\/home\/dbw\/src//}"`.

It looks to me like the problem is that I am not escaping slashes in the replacement expression correctly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose this would be an easy plugin, but that seems excessive.  The  build system seems *made* to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this, and it works.

```
"working_dir": "/home/dbw/bld${file_path/.home.dbw.src//}"
```

It still seems a bit inelegant to me, though.